# How to write and configure a custom provider for ASP.Net Healthmonitoring?

Tags: c#, asp.net, health-monitoring

I'm looking for a walkthrough on how to create and use a custom provider for ASP.Net Healthmonitoring.

So far I've only worked with the e-mail provider that generates e-mails on errors. Basically I want to do the same, but with more flexibility:
I want to use the HealthMonitoring features (I don't want to use the Application_OnError event in the global.asax) in a way that allows me have access to an event, that gets thrown like "OnNewHealthMonitoringEntry" with all the information provided in the e-mail, to run custom code.

**Edit:**
Based on the source code provided here http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-provider-for-logging-health-monitoring-events I was able to build my own custom provider and implement it.  Now I want to add some new attributes to configure my custom provider.
Here is what the web.config looks like:

```
<healthMonitoring>
    <bufferModes>
        <add name="Log Notification" maxBufferSize="1" maxFlushSize="1" urgentFlushThreshold="1" regularFlushInterval="Infinite" urgentFlushInterval="00:00:10"/>
    </bufferModes>
    <providers>
        <add name="FileEventProvider" buffer="true" bufferMode="Log Notification" type="healthmonitoringtest.FileHealthMonitorEventProvider"/>
    </providers>
    <profiles>
        <add name="Custom" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:00:00"/>
    </profiles>
    <rules>
        <add name="File Event Provider" eventName="All Errors" provider="FileEventProvider" profile="Custom"/>
    </rules>
</healthMonitoring>
```

If I attempt to add an attribute to the provider, like this

```
<providers>
    <add name="FileEventProvider" buffer="true" bufferMode="Log Notification" foo="bar"  type="healthmonitoringtest.FileHealthMonitorEventProvider"/>
</providers>
```

I'll get an error saying:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException'
>   occurred in System.Web.dll but was not
>   handled in user code Additional
>   information: Unexpected attribute foo
>   in the configuration of the
>   FileEventProvider.

Is it possible to store configuration necessary for custom provider close to the healthMonitoring section? I guess I could include the settings into the appSettings node, but I'd like to configure it somehow with attributes (inside the healthMonitoring node). Is that possible?

**Edit2**:
You might take a look at this article: http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/6/asp.net/how-to-create-a-custom-healthmonitoring-provider-that-sends-e-mails

Comment: What part of the link you found was unclear?  Perhaps if we start there then we can provide a good answer for you.

Comment: With 'unclear' I meant if my approach using this code sample is the correct way to go to use a custom provider or if it is some old deprecated code

Comment: I edited my question and added an error trying to use arbitrary attributes for the provider. My google searches didn't turn up answers relevant to my sitution. (It also didn't feel right to open a new question for this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [series of articles](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102851/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031407-1.aspx) will take you through the basics of using the Health Monitoring System upto creating Custom Events.

Then the following [26 minute video](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-provider-for-logging-health-monitoring-events) will take you through creating a custom provider that records events to a text-based log file.

**UPDATE Based on Comment**

Looking at your update and using Reflector to look at the source for the `BufferedWebEventProvider` class that you base your custom provider on, I have found that the Initialize method in `BufferedWebEventProvider` does a check at the end to see if there are any attributes that it doesn't recognize. This is done by removing values from the config NameValueCollection parameter as soon as they are assigned to the properties or fields of the `BufferedWebEventProvider`. Then a check is done to see if the config parameter is empty and if not that means that there are extra attributes added, which causes an exception to be thrown.

As to how to fix this problem, one option is to:

1. Move the call to base.Initialize to the end of the method
2. Remove the additional attributes as soon as you assign them to variables just like the provider does.

Something like the following would work:

```
public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
    {
        foo = config["foo"];
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(foo))
        {
            // You can set a default value for foo
        }

        //remove foo from the config just like BufferedWebEventProvider with the other
        //attributes. Note that it doesn't matter if someone didn't proivde a foo attribute
        //because the NameValueCollection remains unchanged if you call its Remove method
        //and the name doesn't exist.
        config.Remove("foo");

        base.Initialize(name, config);
    }
```

Hopefully this works out for you.

Comment: Thanks, the video provided me with all the necessary information

Comment: @citronas Happy to be of service :)

Comment: ;) Sorry that I unmarked your answer as accepted, but I stumbled across a configuration problem with my custom provider. Would you mind taking a second look? =) I edited my question

Comment: @citronas I have updated my answer based on the update to your question

Comment: Wow thanks, such a quick and perfect edit, thanks ;) I also used the reflector but I only looked at the MailProvider class and some of the intern ProviderUtil methods. I thought the exception occured due to some xml dtd and quit the search. Now I feel dumb and lazy :-| I wish I could you more than one upvote. Have a nice evening

Comment: OMG, now I see that the CheckUnrecognizedAttributes was only one treeview node above from the method I viewed last :-|

Comment: @citronas you were actually pretty close. ProviderUtil.CheckUnrecognizedAttributes is the method that checks if there are any values in the config parameter. This method is called at the end of the Initialize method in the BufferedWebEventProvider class. I am happy it all worked out for you :)

Comment: @citronas you realized you were so close just before I added that last comment stating the same thing :)